# Django: Upload Image to database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to upload an image from input field but when I check from database (using Value in Editor), it shows a text which is a file name. I'm new to uploading image, so I'm not sure what's missing in my code. I added media root on settings.py and urls.py. Here is my code.

*models.py*

```
class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    idupload = models.AutoField(db_column='idupload', primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(db_column='image', upload_to="media/", null=True)
    description = models.CharField(db_column='description', max_length=50, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'image_upload'
```

*upload.html*

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Upload File</label>
         <input class="form-control" name="image" type="file" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Description</label>
         <input class="form-control" name="description" required>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-gray-800 mt-2 animate-up-
                    
</form>
```

*views.py*

```
def uploadImage(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'upload.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        ImageUpload.objects.create(image=image, description=description)
        return redirect('/images/')
```

I tried above code but I kept on getting nothing.

Comment: only filename will be saved in the database.

Comment: @SuhailPIXL yes, but I don't know how to save the image itself.

Comment: @nana you **shouldn't** save the images in the database, see: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) The image you uploaded would have been saved in the filepath with your current code.

Comment: @nana: on the disk or some third party storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I did it.

```
def uploadImage(request):
    item = ImageUpload()
    item.description = request.POST.get('description')
    if len(request.FILES) != 0:
        item.image = request.FILES['image']
        item.save()
        return redirect('/images/')
```

And here is how I view the images in html.

```
{% for obj in item %}
<div class="card-body">
    <div><img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" alt=""></div>
    <div>DESCRIPTION: {{ obj.description }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CreateView` this will save the Image into your media folder.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import ImageUpload
class UploadView(CreateView):
    model = ImageUpload
    fields = ['image','description' ]
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...<other url patterns>...
    path('', views.UploadView.as_view(), name='fileupload'),
]
```

tempates `myapp/imageupload_form.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```